# <a> taller than its <img> child

Tags: html, css, height, positioning

On my website a banner image has a certain height (responsive) but it has an overlay (`#vignette`) which is nested inside an a-tag together with the banner image. #vignette gets its height from its parent:

```
#vignette  {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35), inset 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And the a-tag adjust its height to its content:

```
a#banner-image {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

How then is it possible that the a-tag is taller than the image itself? Can't seem to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Why an image inside a div has an extra space below the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ensure the `img` is displayed as a block element.

```
a#banner-image img {
    display: block;
}
```

As @Ianzz correctly states, this is because of an issue with descender space for all inline elements.

Comment: This is not an issue with adjacent whitespace, but with descender space for all inline elements.

Comment: Thank you! Never though that an img would nót be displayed as block.